# Rails installed Gem not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I had that problem installed Gem not loading
At my local pc, works well. 
But at my server, not worked.

**undefined Constant,,, undefined method..about added gem**

I tried to find the reason why not loaded at server in spite of Gem installed well 
I dont know!! 
and just I was trying to restart not only unicorn but also nginx.

**(more detail.. unicorn stop -> nginx restart -> unicorn start)**

and then gem is loaded!! it works well.

Why is the gem not loaded at 'only unicorn restart' run when deploy to server (capistrano)  ??

(in this case, the gem is kaminari)

Do I add not only **unicorn restart code** but also **the nginx restart code** to deploy.rb ?